# My progress bar is vertical , I want it to be horizontal

Tags: swift

The progress bar is horizontal in my Xcode view, however when I run my app it shows as vertical.

I want it to be horizontal... how can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your code that is showing the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem was auto layout, (which was suggested earlier here) however at first I didnt think it could be auto layout, but it was because I had not changed the view in Xcode to the view of iPhone apps.